# Marriage in Rig-Veda

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, marriage, women, widow

Here are the verses in question
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc838695.html
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc838696.html

The first verse mentions "not a widow" I am wondering how this is translated. Does it put widows in a negative light or say women shouldn't be widows and be happy? The second verse in a commentary by Sayana says that the verse for remarriage is in question with the brother of the father. So does this mean a woman isn't free to remarry whoever she chooses? I think I am thinking about this too much when it doesn't need to be, but these verses I acknowledge mention the welfare of women I just wish to know how/if they are more restrictive. Other Rig Vedic verses would help. I am in no authority due to my knowledge to explain the Vedas, so anyone who is learned should answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Rigved 10.18 sukta is sung when a person is died and whose wife is crying, In 7th mantr "not a widow" is mentioned because widow is crying for her husband, and next mantr i.e. 8th is not for remarriage, sayanācharya is commenting that Widow's brother in law should say to the widow to leave the body and go to her home to her family children/sons and grandchildren/grandsons.